# Change only one of the many iteration

Tags: java

I have 0-10 for loop I want to change the value to 100 when is only 4 and the rest will not be affected and no break how should I achieve that. And as for the petitioner, do not repel [him].

```java
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("Hello world!");

        int n = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // for example
      
            /*
                0           0
                1           1
                2           2
                3           3
                4 = 100     100
                5           5
                6           6
                7           7
                8           8
                9           9
                10          10
            */
    
            if (i == 4)
            {
                i = 100;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? what is your question?

Comment: what do you want to do with the 100 value? At the moment your code, when i == 4 will set i to 100 and then on the next for loop it will break out of the loop as i is now greater than 10

Comment: Check the comment I left and it might make sense to you.

Comment: I would also like to point out that your variable `n` is unused

Comment: I don't need that variable anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another Solution!!

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("Hello world!");


        for (int i = 0; i <=10; i++)
        {
            // for example
      
            /*
                0           0
                1           1
                2           2
                3           3
                4 = 100     100
                5           5
                6           6
                7           7
                8           8
                9           9
                10          10
            */
    
            if (i == 4)
            {
                i = 100;
                System.out.println(i);
                i=4;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This one !!

```
class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.println("Hello world!");


   

       
       for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
           // for example


       /*
       0           0
       1           1
       2           2
       3           3
       4 = 100     100
       5           5
       6           6
       7           7
       8           8
       9           9
       10          10
       */
       if(i == 4){
       System.out.println ("100");
       }else{
       System.out.println(i);
 
       }
       }
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution suggestion, but this feels like a solution I can only get it from inside a dream.